# Extract two columns from file using and sort 2nd column

Tags: bash, centos, awk, sed, grep

Have a file with the following format...

```
ATOM    126  CD  GLN A 449      -2.853  11.592 119.709  1.00 17.95           C  
ATOM    127  OE1 GLN A 449      -4.056  11.297 119.695  1.00 20.83           O  
ATOM    128  NE2 GLN A 449      -1.948  10.876 120.359  1.00 14.98           N  
HETATM  129  N   MSE A 450      -4.523  16.830 119.280  1.00 14.88           N  
HETATM  130  CA  MSE A 450      -5.537  17.804 118.911  1.00 15.65           C
```

There are several hundred lines in this file with various names in the first column. I wish to extract the rows called ATOM (in the 1st column) and the 11th column values of ATOM. Then sort the values (smallest to largest). How do I do this using grep or awk or sed or similar and output to a .txt file.

Comment: [edit] your question to include the expected output given your posted sample input plus what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '$1=="ATOM"{print $11}' file | sort -n > foo.txt
```

or:

```
awk '$1=="ATOM"{print $1, $11}' file | sort -k2,2n > foo.txt
```

depending if you want ATOM included in the output or not.

Answer (score 1):

While `awk` is definitely the way to go, here is an alternative using nested capture groups where you....

```
sed -En "s/^(^ATOM)(( +)([^ ]+)){10}.*/\1 \4/p" file | sort -n
ATOM 14.98
ATOM 17.95
ATOM 20.83

sed -En "s/(^ATOM)(( +)([^ ]+)){10}.*/\4/p" file | sort -n
14.98
17.95
20.83
```

**Walkthrough**

`sed` using `-E`xtended regex `-n`ot printing lines by default then `s/`ubstitute using

- `\1` is the first capture in `(^ATOM)` (`^` anchoring to the start of the line so it's the first field),
- `\2` is the `{10}`th subsequent repetition of `(( +)([^ ]+))`,
- `\3` is the `( +)` within that repetition and
- `\4` is the `([^ ]+)` that you want within the same repetition (the 11th field).
- and you don't need to capture the last `.*`

Then recompose your output from your captured groups as `/\1 \4/` or `/\4/`to suit and `p`rint any line with a successful substitution.

Answer (score 0):

you could use string manipulation to remove unwanted whitespaces from strings. that would leave you useable delimiter for `cut -d` (whitespace or tab)

```
var="$(cat input.txt)"

echo "${var//+( )/$'\t'}" | cut -f1,11 | sort -nk2 > output.txt
```

`//` replace all occurences
`+( )` matches whitespaces
`$'\t'` tabulator

`cut -f` will output field `1,11`
`sort -n` will sort numeric
`-k` beginning on word `2`

Comment: `var="$(grep ^ATOM input.txt)"` if filtering for ATOM is wanted